# java script parsing error during jenkins nightly build. after upgrading sonar to 4.3.2

Tags: java, javascript, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

After upgrading sonar from **3.4** to **4.3.2** version, we are getting java script parsing error during jenkins nightly build. It was all working fine in last version.The sonar runner is still of version 2. COuld you please  advice on resolving this error. The plugin used is `sonar-javascript-plugin-1.6`, `sonar-squid-java-plugin-1.6`.

Error details:

```
[INFO] [12:56:47.163] Sensor JavaScriptSquidSensor...
[INFO] [12:56:47.275] 98 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] [12:56:57.330] 10/98 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Nightly_Build_abc_CAD_src/workspace/abc_CAD_src/src/main/webapp/auth/js/lib/angular/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js
[ERROR] [12:57:01.429] Unable to parse file: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Nightly_Build_abc_CAD_src/workspace/abc_CAD_src/src/main/webapp/js/lib/csrfguard.js
com.sonar.sslr.api.RecognitionException: Parse error at line 199 column 13 failed to match all of: spacing IDENTIFIER NULL TRUE FALSE NUMERIC_LITERAL stringLiteral REGULAR_EXPRESSION_LITERAL LBRACKET LCURLYBRACE LPARENTHESIS FUNCTION NEW THIS IDENTIFIER NULL TRUE FALSE NUMERIC_LITERAL stringLiteral REGULAR_EXPRESSION_LITERAL LBRACKET LCURLYBRACE LPARENTHESIS FUNCTION NEW NEW THIS IDENTIFIER NULL TRUE FALSE NUMERIC_LITERAL stringLiteral REGULAR_EXPRESSION_LITERAL LBRACKET LCURLYBRACE LPARENTHESIS FUNCTION NEW THIS IDENTIFIER NULL TRUE FALSE NUMERIC_LITERAL stringLiteral REGULAR_EXPRESSION_LITERAL LBRACKET LCURLYBRACE LPARENTHESIS FUNCTION NEW NEW DELETE VOID TYPEOF INC DEC PLUS MINUS TILDA BANG
```

Comment: Could you provide the piece of code that includes line 199 of your file "src/main/webapp/js/lib/csrfguard.js" please ? There is maybe a bug in the parser.
The upgrade of SonarQube plateform should not have consequence on the way the plugin parses the sources. Has the file been changed before the build ?

Comment: @Linda : no changes have been done to the file before the build. 189:   window.XMLHttpRequest = init_XMLHttpRequest;
190:  }
191: 
192:  /** check if valid domain based on domainStrict **/
193:  function isValidDomain(current, target) {
194:   var result = false;
195:   
196:   /** check exact or subdomain match **/
197:   if(current == target) {
198:    result = true;
199:   } else if(%DOMAIN_STRICT% == false) {
                ^
200:    if(target.charAt == '.') {
201:     result = current.endsWith(target);
202:    } else {
203:     result = current.endsWith('.' + target);
204:    }

Comment: Can you confirm that the file was analysed before (you were able to see it from UI)? Maybe was it excluded or not in the source directory given to sonarqube and was after the upgrdae?
In any case the parse error occurs because of "%DOMAIN_STRICT%" (line 199 column 13) which is not an allowed construct? Is it ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This file is one of the files in lob folder and is included under exclusions in pom.xml but I don’t understand why is it not getting ignored. We have 
<sonar.exclusions>js/lib/*.js,auth/js/lib/**/*.js,js/lib/**/**/*.js</sonar.exclusions>

I also added it as sonar properties but still getting the same error. 
-Dsonar.exclusions=js/lib/*.js,auth/js/lib/**/*.js,js/lib/**/**/*.js

Kindly advice.

Comment: @linda: kindkly reply:P

Answer (score 0):

As clarified in the comments on the OP, your parsing errors are a result of some previously-excluded files no longer being excluded from the analysis. Those files are now included because your exclusions are specified at analysis time (i.e. in pom.xml or sonar-project.properties), and that is no longer supported. I believe that happened in [3.5](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=11694&version=18825)

To eliminate the parsing errors, you'll need to re-specify your exclusions into the interface. [The docs](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus) should help.

Comment: on  Sonar dashboard, 
Under Project name->Category->Exclusions->Files->Source File Exclusions, we included the below but it is still throwing the same error. why is it not considering the exclusions as it did used to do in previous versions ? What is missing still to consider exclusions?

Comment: js/lib/*.js,auth/js/lib/**/*.js,js/lib/**/**/*.js

Comment: @user3932272 you set those up as separate entries, right? Also, your 3rd pattern can be simplified to this: js/lib/**/*.js. "**" is essentially "*" for directories. Finally, I believe the first pattern can be eliminated, because what it covers is included in the third pattern.

Comment: yes we are using them as separate entries but still the issue remains.

Comment: What is your sonar.sources value?

Comment: sonar.sources=src/main/webapp

Comment: in previous version we used to add project name before src but now if we do that it takes double path name for project. eg: if we add sonar.sources=abc_project/src/main/webapp , in console output the build would fail stating that path abc_project/abc_project/src/main/webapp not found.

Comment: @user3932272 you need to specify exclusions starting from "src/main..." [the docs](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-patterns)

Comment: I think we're proving that this is not the format for debugging issues. You should raise this issue on the user mailing list.