# "@" character making jenkins error cannot parse file

Tags: jenkins, laravel-blade

I currently got this error when building with jenkins

```
ERROR: Unable to parse file: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/vcl/resources/views/scr2131.blade.php
ERROR: Parse error at line 11 column 23:

<!-- <% unless @max_results %>-->
```

It just a comment line in those blade file (i'm using laravel).
This file is the common file and it kind of hard to have permission to change anything. Is there anything I can do to make Jenkins pass this error?

Answer (score 1):

> I can do to make Jenkins pass this error?

Jenkins itself does not parse those files.

One of your Jenkins job build *step* does.

So the question becomes: How can I make that step *not* fail when parsing that php file.

It depends *what* actually is that step: error parsing are often seen during a [SonarQube analysis as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25260674/6309).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't shared you pipeline code, so it is hard to be specific, but you can try to wrap the line(s) in which are causing problems within try block and than catch and suppress errors

```
try {
   //put problematic parse command here
}
catch(Exception e) {
   println "suppressing error."
   //you can also add validation if the error is the one which you expected. If not you may rethrow the error.
}
```

If the exception is caught and handled, Jenkins will continue the job.